# dynamic fitness function for genetic algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm, job-scheduling

I'm not sure if I'm completely understanding genetic algorithms and how they work, I'm trying to learn via ai4r http://ai4r.rubyforge.org/geneticAlgorithms.html

If in Job Shop Scheduling, which I believe can be solved by GA(?), isn't cost of any single job is based on how it related to it's predecessors? I was thinking I would calculate a cost based on the placement of the chromosome with a dynamic score of how well it is placed rather than a binary value, but I'm not sure this works.

Anybody have any experience with this? or does a GA only work when the difference between any two genomes is static?

I hope I have the right terminology here, as I mentioned, I'm just learning.

-----------------------update-----------------------------------

I think I'm using a bit of the wrong terminology here. I referred to 'fitness' when I think what I actually wanted to use was `cost matrix`.

The example I'm going from describes this

```
Each chromosome must represent a posible solution for the problem. This class conatins an array with the list of visited nodes (cities of the tour). The size of the tour is obtained automatically from the traveling costs matrix. You have to assign the costs matrix BEFORE you run the genetic search. The following costs matrix could be used to solve the problem with only 3 cities:


data_set = [    [ 0, 10, 5],
        [ 6,  0, 4],
        [25,  4, 0]
    ]
Ai4r::GeneticAlgorithm::Chromosome.set_cost_matrix(data_set)
```

so in my instance, I'm thinking the 'cost' of each chromosome is dynamic based on it's neighbours.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the fitness of any single job". Your fitness here will be computed over all the jobs. Typically for JSP, you pick something like minimizing the makespan, i.e., the time between when the first job starts and the last one ends.

In terms of static vs. dynamic, you can apply GAs to dynamic fitness functions. The basic approach is to somehow average or otherwise combine multiple evaluations of a point into the fitness of that point. But I'm not sure that's really relevant here. JSP is generally static when properly modeled.

Comment: @deong, I used the wrong terminology, sorry for the confusion, I was thinking the fitness of a single chromosome when I should have said the cost. I've updated the question to hopefully clarify.

Comment: So yes, the cost contributed by a single job does depend on its neighbors, but you don't really care about that, because the GA isn't operating on individual jobs, only on complete schedules. Think about something like the traveling salesman problem. The cost of visiting one city depends on which city you visit it from, but the overall problem -- the matrix contain all the city-city distances -- is static. You don't need to do anything fancy with a dynamic GA. Same thing here.

Comment: @deong, if the travelling salesman had to be in paris at 2pm on thursday, then I have to score how the neighbors relate based on they fit with the schedule. So that is why I'm wondering if adding a dynamic cost would work.

Comment: That's still not really how I'd approach the problem. You don't score individual cities at all. If a complete tour puts him in Paris after 2:00, you either modify the tour (maybe by swapping the position of Paris with some earlier city) or you add a penalty term **to the entire tour**. You could add some sort of consideration of what you're calling "dynamic cost" into, e.g., the process of generating initial random solutions, into a local search operator embedded into your GA, or into your mutation operator. But for a standard GA, no, there's really nothing dynamic in JSP.

Comment: Your intuition that job-shop scheduling and TSP are not good early projects for learning GAs is spot on. GAs rely on short sequences meaningfully contributing to overall fitness, and you are exactly right in thinking "wait a minute" when the task has internal dependencies such that a good idea "over here" is not stable depending on the expression of a portion of the genome "way over there." Yes, it can be gotten around by different encoding or expression schemes, but (IMO) other tasks are better for initial exposure to the concepts. Bin packing would be better, but still not ideal.

Comment: @deong, if I understand the 'penalty term' correctly, you're suggesting that any solution of the GA which does not match an acceptable order automatically has a penalty applied to it. Is that correct?  If you can explain "penalty term" in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @LarryOBrien, thanks for your input. I'm playing with something of a sort-order/job-placement along a timeline, and though I am actually now seeing a use for bin-packing, I think that may be a bit of later stage learning for me, thanks for the input and expanding my mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked in a comment to make this an answer, I took the liberty of summarizing my earlier responses as well so it's all in one place. The answer to the specific question of "what is a penalty term" is in item #3 below.

The way a standard genetic algorithm works is that each "chromosome" is a complete solution to the problem. In your case, an ordering for the jobs to be submitted. The confusion, I think, centers around the notion that because the individual contributions to fitness made by a particular job in that schedule varies according to the rest of the schedule, you must need something "dynamic". That's not really true. From the point of view of the GA, the only thing that has a fitness is the entire solution. So a dynamic problem is one in which the fitness of a whole schedule can change over time. Going back to the TSP, a dynamic problem would be one in which touring cities in order of A, B, C, D, and then E actually had a different distance each time you tried it. Even though the cost of a tour through B depends on which cities come before and after B in the tour, once you decide that, the costs are static, and because the GA only ever receives costs for entire tours, all it knows is that [A,B,C,D,E] has a constant fitness. No dynamic trickery needed.

Now, your second question was how to handle constraints like, for the TSP example, what if you need to ensure that the salesman gets to Paris by a certain time? Typically, there are three ways to try to handle this.

1. Never allow a solution to be generated in which he doesn't get there before 2:00. Sometimes this is easy, other times it's very hard. For instance, if the constraint was "he cannot start at city X", it's fairly easy to just not generate solutions that don't start with X. Often though, simply finding valid solutions can be hard, and so this approach doesn't really work.
2. Allow constraints to be violated, but fix them afterward. In the TSP example, you let crossover and mutation produce any possible tour, but then scan through it to see if he gets to Paris too late. If so, swap the position of Paris with some earlier city in the tour. Again though, sometimes it can be hard to figure out a good way to repair violations.
3. Penalize the fitness of an infeasible solution. Here, the idea is that even if I can't prevent him from getting to Paris too late and I can't fix it if he does, I can at least make the fitness arbitrarily worse. For TSP, the fitness is the length of the tour. So you might say that if a tour gets him to Paris too late, the fitness is the length of the tour + 100. That let's the solution stay in the population (it might be very good otherwise, so you want it to have a chance to pass on some of its genes), but you make it less likely to be selected, because your selection and replacement methods pick individuals with better fitness values.

For your JSP problem, typically you're looking to minimize the makespan. The same three options are available to you if you do have some constraints. But from what I can tell, you don't really have such constraints. I think you're trying to inject too much knowledge into the process rather than letting the evolutionary algorithm come up with it on its own. That is, you don't necessarily worry about telling the GA that some arrangements of jobs are better than others. You just assign higher fitness to the better ones and let the process converge.

That said, injecting information like this is often a really good thing to do, but you want to have a good understanding of the basic algorithm first. Let's say that we know that for TSP, it's more likely that a good solution will connect cities that are close to one another. The way I would use that information inside a GA would be to generate random solutions non-uniformly (perhaps with a greedy heuristic). I might also replace the standard crossover and mutation algorithms with something customized. Mutation is typically easier to do this with than crossover. To mutate a TSP solution, I might pick two connected cities, break the connection, and then look for a way to reconnect them that was "closer". That is, if a tour is [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H], I might pick the edge [B,C] at random, and then look for another edge, maybe [F,G], such that when I connected them crossways to get [A,B,G,D,E,F,C,H], the total tour length was lower. I could even extend that mutation beyond one step -- create a loop that keeps trying to break and reconnect edges until it can't find a shorter tour. This leads to what is usually called a hybrid GA because it's a GA hybridized with a local search; sometimes also called a Memetic Algorithm. These sorts of algorithms usually outperform a black-box GA because you're giving the algorithm "hints" to bias it towards trying things you expect to be good.

I think this idea of a memetic algorithm is pretty close to what you were hitting on in your original question of wondering how to deal with the fact that the contribution to fitness from a particular job depends on where the other jobs are in the schedule. The only stumbling block there is that you were a bit unlucky in that the somewhat reasonable idea of thinking of this as "dynamic" leads you a bit astray, as "dynamic" actually means something entirely different here.

So to wrap up, there's nothing "dynamic" about your problem, so the things people do with GAs for dynamic problems will be entirely unhelpful. A standard GA will work with no fancy tricks. However, the idea of using information you have about what schedules work better **can** be introduced into the genetic operators, and will probably result in a significantly better overall algorithm.

Comment: thanks @deong, that was simply amazing! As I am just learning, I never would have known about memetic algorithms, and for now I'll learn more about GAs but you've definitely given me a longer path of learning.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use GA to find say the best order to do a number of jobs in, or those jobs which made say best use of a day's resources. So yes they'd be related to each other.

So your fitness measure would be for seq 1,3,4,5,6,2.

Look at say find shortest path algorithm, starts to make sense then

Comment: I updated the question as I was using the wrong terminology. I should have said the cost of the chromosome, not the fitness. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The chromsone shouldn't be an individual job, it should be an ordered sequence of them. So if you had eight jobs, 24 bits would describe the chomosone, then you caldulate teh fitness, then you bin X worst, mutate the remainder and go again. After X iterations you end up with X fittest chomosones the same, where X is this will do.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Not sure you intended the "24 bits" thing literally, but don't use binary encodings here. The chromosome should be a permutation directly, and the algorithm should use crossover operators like Cycle crossover, Order Crossover, etc., that respect permutations.

Comment: Probably not. 8 ints I should think, crunching it down not worth the effort. Must have had binary stuck in my head..